# Play! How to retrieve field value in a template tag having entity and the field name passed separately as parameters?

Tags: playframework

I wanted to create a tag like:

```
#{some_tag entity:user, field:'name'}
```

and expect it to produce some output with the user name in it by using expression like:

```
${_entity._field}
```

I know it doesn't work but that's why I ask here.
Is there a simple way to use a field name passed as a parameter to a template tag to get the field value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of an easy answer, but it is possible. You can create a fast tag, and use reflection to get the field you are after.
You can get more info on Fast Tags here - [Can someone explain how to use FastTags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135529/can-someone-explain-how-to-use-fasttags/4136847#4136847)

However, wouldnt it be easier to just send the specific field through to your tag?

Comment: I have to use both: the field name and the field value so I wanted to compress the parameters list. If there is no _easy_ way to do it I'll use the extended parameters list.

Answer (score 3):

When I needed to do this I did something similar to the CRUD module.  I call the tag as `#{sometag 'entity.field' /}`

then in the fast tag I have (roughly):

```
String[] parts = args.get("arg").split("\\.");
Object entity = play.mvc.Scope.RenderArgs.current().get(parts[0]);
String field = String.valueOf(parts[1]);
Object value = groovy.util.Eval.me("_caller", template.template, "_caller." + args.get("arg").replace(".", "?."));
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are stored in a variable called renderArgs. I'm not sure if this is directly accessible inside templates, but if this doesn't work:

```
renderArgs.get(_entity)
```

then you can probably access it indirectly using the static method:

```
Scope.RenderArgs.current().get(_entity)
```

Accessing a named field of that entity is then a matter of reflection.

However, I agree with the suggestion that there has to be an easier way. If you find yourself doing reflection like that, it *usually* (not always) means you've over-engineered something.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass those parameters to a utility class that uses reflection to find the String value you actually want displayed.

```
${play.sample.util.ReflectUtil.get(_entity, _field)}
```

play.sample.util.ReflectUtil:

```
public static String get(String entity, String field) {
    String displayValue = ... // look up value ... 
    return displayValue;
}
```

Or a FastTag would work too.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works with easy way. I have pager tag:

```
#{pager model:productList, totalCount:total /}
```

And in pager.tag i have:

```
<div class="total">${_totalCount}</div>
<ul>
#{list items:_model.getStartPage(params.pageNumber).._model.getPageCount(params.pageNumber), as:'i'}
%{selectedClass=i.toString()==(params.pageNumber==null? "1" : params.pageNumber)?"selected":""%}
<li class="${selectedClass}">
    #{if selectedClass == "selected"}
    <span>${i}</span>
    #{/if}
    #{else}
    <a href="@{Product.list(params.categoryId, params.rangeStart, params.rangeEnd, params.brandId, i, params.pageSize, params.q)}">${i}</a>
    #{/else}
</li>
#{/list}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but having read your code several times I still don't get where is the part answering my question.

Comment: Your question is: how to pass entity and field name to template tag, right? I just showed you a working example how to achieve this. Maybe I just missed something.

Comment: As far as I see you pass some entity and a number. There is no place in your code where you get the field value using its _name_ (not the value passed as a parameter). Look closely at the examples given in the question.

Comment: _model.getStartPage in the code. You can call field the same way the method. Maybe I just misunderstood your question. Sorry