# How to extend Play! Framework template tags

Tags: playframework, rendering, templatetags

I'd like to extend the built in `#{a` template tag. For example, instead of writing every time:

```
#{a @Controller.Action(parameter.slugify()) /}
```

Where if `parameter="This Is a Test"` then the generated `href` is `http://localhost/controller/action/this-is-a-test`

I'd like to extend it so that the parameter is always slugified by default without explicitly doing it with `.slugify()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is define your own fast tags. There is a good example [here](http://playframework.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/fasttags-in-play/).
Check this answer as [well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135529/can-someone-explain-how-to-use-fasttags).

The code would probably look like this:

```java
@FastTags.Namespace("mytags")
public class MyTags extends play.templates.FastTags{


    public static void _a(Map<?, ?> args, Closure body, PrintWriter out, ExecutableTemplate template, int fromLine) {
        ActionDefinition actionDef = (ActionDefinition) args.get("arg");
        if (actionDef == null) {
            actionDef = (ActionDefinition) args.get("action");
        }
        if (!("GET".equals(actionDef.method))) {
            if (!("POST".equals(actionDef.method))) {
                String separator = actionDef.url.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&" : "?";
                actionDef.url += separator + "x-http-method-override=" + actionDef.method;
                actionDef.method = "POST";
            }
            String id = Codec.UUID();
            out.print("<form method=\"POST\" id=\"" + id + "\" " +(args.containsKey("target") ? "target=\"" + args.get("target") + "\"" : "")+ " style=\"display:none\" action=\"" + actionDef.url + "\">");
            _authenticityToken(args, body, out, template, fromLine);
            out.print("</form>");
            out.print("<a href=\"javascript:document.getElementById('" + id + "').submit();\" " + serialize(args, "href") + ">");
            out.print(JavaExtensions.toString(body));
            out.print("</a>");
        } else {
            out.print("<a href=\"" + actionDef.url + "\" " + JavaExtensions.slugify(serialize(args, "href")) + ">");
            out.print(JavaExtensions.toString(body));
            out.print("</a>");
        }
    }
}
```

and be called like this in your template:

```
#{mytags.a @Controller.Action(parameter) /}
```